# kernel mode timer

Tags: windows, timer, kernel, driver, mode

How can I have a timer in kernel mode such that a specified function in my driver is called approximately every second on Windows XP and above? I should be able to use all functions (in particular ZwQuerySystemInformation) in the function. I do not need a high resolution timer or millisecond accuracy or anything like that, I just need a way to schedule a function to be run about once per second in kernel mode and it must work on all 32 bit systems windows xp and higher.

Answer (score 5):

Create a kernel timer via [KeInitializeTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552168%28VS.85%29.aspx).
Set the timer with [KeSetTimerEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553292%28VS.85%29.aspx) and use a period of 1s.
Create a thread in your driver.
In the thread, call [KeWaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553350%28VS.85%29.aspx) to wait on the timer and upon return, call your function.
Repeat.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [KeDelayExecutionThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551986%28VS.85%29.aspx) within a loop in your thread.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of wasting a thread, you can also use a dpc object to get a callback at dispatch level when the timer expires.  Just pass it as the dpc argument for KeSetTimerEx.